# jenkins integration with maven issue

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins, testng

Facing PluginResolutionException while executing code from jenkins. When I am executing the same code from eclipse then it works, but it is not working in jenkins. It shows me pluginResolutionexception.

```
public class LoginPageTest extends TestBase {

LoginPage loginpage;
EnquiryPage enquirypage;
HomePage homepage;

public ExcelToDataProvider dataproviderclass = new ExcelToDataProvider();
String xlfilepath = "E:\\ExcelData.xlsx";
String sheetname = "Sheet1";
WaitHelper waithelper;
static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoginPageTest.class);

public LoginPageTest() {
    super();
}

@BeforeTest
public void setUp1() {
    initialization();
    loginpage = new LoginPage();
    enquirypage = new EnquiryPage();
    waithelper = new WaitHelper(driver);

    PropertyConfigurator.configure(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\"+XpathClass.log4jProp);
}

@Test(dataProvider = "userData", dataProviderClass = ExcelToDataProvider.class)
public void loginMethod(String username, String password) throws InterruptedException {

    homepage = loginpage.login(username, password);
    logger.info("login method executed");

}

@Test(dataProvider = "enquiryData", dataProviderClass = ExcelToDataProvider.class, dependsOnMethods = {"loginMethod"})
public void addEnquiry_validDetails(String name, String phNum, String emailId, String gender, String birthday, String birthMonth, String birthYr, String country, String sourceName, String institutename, String standard, String sub1, String sub2, String masterCourse, String course1, String course2, String enquiryPriority, String followuptype, String walkinDay, String walkinmonth, String walkinyr,String refferedName, String branch, String assignto,String comments )
        throws Exception {
    logger.info("*********************************************************************");
    enquirypage.add_Enquiry();
    enquirypage.stud_information(name,phNum,emailId,gender,birthday, birthMonth,birthYr, country, sourceName,institutename,standard, sub1, sub2,masterCourse,course1, course2,enquiryPriority,followuptype, walkinDay,  walkinmonth,  walkinyr, refferedName,  branch,  assignto, comments);


}
   }
```

This is testng.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="testScripts.LoginPageTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

This is my POM.xml file. I have linked this pom.xml file path in jenkins. Still it is showing the error

```
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>project</groupId>
    <artifactId>proctur</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>proctur</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.53.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
            <!-- <scope>test</scope> -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.inject/guice -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>4.0-beta</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.velocity/velocity -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.uncommons/reportng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.uncommons</groupId>
            <artifactId>reportng</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>18.0</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0</version>

                <!-- <configuration> <mainClass>testScripts.LoginPageTest</mainClass> 
                    </configuration> -->
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.1</version>
                <configuration>

                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>testScripts.LoginPageTest</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- <plugin> <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> <version>3.5.1</version> 
                <configuration> <source>1.8</source> <target>1.8</target> <fork>true</fork> 
                <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\bin\javac.exe</executable> 
                </configuration> </plugin> -->

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>


FailedConsole Output
Started by user ashwini
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\Users\Proctur\.jenkins\workspace\Proctur_AutomationProject
Parsing POMs
Established TCP socket on 61274
[proctur] $ "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212/bin/java" -cp C:\Users\Proctur\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven35-agent-1.13.jar;C:\Users\Proctur\.jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\Maven\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\Proctur\.jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\Maven/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main C:\Users\Proctur\.jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\Maven C:\Users\Proctur\.jenkins\war\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-3.29.jar C:\Users\Proctur\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven35-interceptor-1.13.jar C:\Users\Proctur\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-1.13.jar 61274
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f E:\New folder\proctur\pom.xml compile test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------------< project:proctur >---------------------------
[INFO] Building proctur 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.20.1/maven-surefire-plugin-2.20.1.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  12.667 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-09-16T16:05:37+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:2.20.1: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.20.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
[JENKINS] Archiving E:\New folder\proctur\pom.xml to project/proctur/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/proctur-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
channel stopped
TestNG Reports Processing: START
Looking for TestNG results report in workspace using pattern: **/*.xml
Did not find any matching files.
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

Your specific issue could be caused by various things.

Are you running Jenkins on the same machine as your eclipse instance ?

The actual error is stated as :

[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:2.20.1: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.20.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org -> [Help 1]

Note : **Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org**

Either the machine Jenkins is running on has no access to the repo (needs proxy perhaps, or has an incorrect hosts entry, etc.)

Or you have incorrect proxy setup on Jenkins itself, start looking at your config in Jenkins.